# Xamarin iOS + Selecting different xcassets based on different targets

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have created different Targets to version our app for different clients. Each client uses different xcassets. Hence we have different xcassets for each target. This way I can have different images with the same names for different targets. And so just by selecting the target, the correct image will get bundled up.

I know this can be done in XCode, but i am not able to find how to do the same in Xamarin using VS 2017 for Mac.

Sorry if this is a very lame query, but i really need some pointers here.
Also if there is someother way to do the task, pointers for that are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add a new project to your solution, then add its reference to your root project.

Secondly we need to modify the **AppDelegate.cs**:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
//let this inherit from the root project's appdelegate
public class AppDelegate2 : AppDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // call the base appdelegate's method to init the window
        base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

        return true;
    }
     ...
}
```

Remove all the useless viewControllers or Main.Storyboard in the new project. From now on we can run the new project successfully. Its content is just a copy from your root project. If it throws an exception(can not find a storyboard called "Main") at first running time, clean it, run again.

At last we can add our image sources in each project. I recommend you to add images to **Resources** folder directly instead of using **Asset Catalogs**. In my test Assets may produce some caches and use the same images in each project depending on the root project's `Asset Catalogs`.

Also when we want to use Assets on Storyboard, there're some issues. So add images as **BundleResource** directly may be a solution. Moreover if you find the second copy project beginning to show the images in root project, delete the bin and obj folders will fix it.